# maven build fails when using allatori obfuscation

Tags: maven, obfuscation, allatori

I have enabled obfuscation using antrun-plugin maven plugin. there is no `keep-names` in my `allatori-config.xml` file:

```
<config>
 <keep-names>
 </keep-names>
  <jars>
    <jar in="${obf.jar}" out="${obf.jar}"/>
  </jars>
  <property name="log-file" value="target/allatori-log.xml"/>
</config>
```

This is how my maven plugin configuration looks:

```
   <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.6</version>
           <executions>
             <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
               <id>obfuscate2</id>
                <configuration>
                 <target unless="${obfuscation.skip}">
                   <echo message="running allatori"/>
                   <property name="obf.jar" value="target/XYZ-${project.version}.jar"/>
                   <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>
                   <taskdef name="allatori" classname="com.allatori.ant.ObfuscatorTask" classpath="${env.ALLATORI_LIB}/allatori.jar:${runtime_classpath}"/>
                   <allatori config="${basedir}/allatori-config.xml"/>
                 </target>
               </configuration>
               <goals>
                 <goal>run</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
          </executions>
       </plugin>
```

I have 2 modules(say A and B) for which I want to perform the obfuscation.
Now module A get obfuscated successfully but the module B(which is dependent on module A) fails to get compiled saying "cannot find symbol" or "package com.mycomp.xyz.schema does not exist"(where these packages belongs to module A).

Is it so that if a later used module get obfuscated first, then the dependent modules fails to get the dependencies or there is anything which I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

So as it says that it fails to find the package and that is very obvious reason. the package along with its contents are obfuscated already.
The solution was to put those of the referred objects in the `<keep-names>` So that they don't get obfuscated.